# Android Login using xampp server, phpmyadmin, eclipse

Tags: android, database, xampp, database-connection

I insert values in database (phpmyadmin) and when I try to connect from my USB Android Device ... nothing happens.

```
package pack.coderzheaven;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidPHPConnectionDemo extends Activity {
    Button b;
    EditText et, pass;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this, "",
                        "Validating user...", true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        login();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }

    void login() {
        try {

            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://127.0.0.1/my_folder_inside_htdocs/check.php"); // make
                                                                                // sure
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // url
                                                                                // is
                                                                                // correct.
            // add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android
            // side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", et.getText()
                    .toString().trim())); // $Edittext_value =
                                            // $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass
                    .getText().toString().trim()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                    responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this,
                                "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this,
                        UserPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                showAlert();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void showAlert() {
        AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this);
                builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
                builder.setMessage("User not Found.")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is a problem with my path? that folder located inside htdocs contains a folder named "my_folder_inside_htdocs" which contains check.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL `http://127.0.0.1/my_folder_inside_htdocs/check.php` is work only from the emulator. To connect from device you have to use your `ip address` instead of `127.0.0.1` like `http://168.155.2.2/my_folder_inside_htdocs/check.php`